How to process tasks as they complete when using TaskGroup?
I understand the arguments for using the newer TaskGroup in place of older mechanisms based on create_task().
However, TaskGroup exits after all tasks are done.  What if you want to start processing the results as soon as the first task finishes, like you can with asyncio.as_completed() or asyncio.wait( ..., return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED )?
If TaskGroup offers no way to do that, then it's a trade-off rather than a strict upgrade, isn't?

@mkrieger1 - I never said it did, but to avoid confusion, I'll remove the reference.

Neither as_completed nor wait has been removed or deprecated.  They are still there, and still supported.  I don't understand how the addition of a new capability can be called anything other than an "upgrade."  But, okay, for the sake of discussion let's call it a "trade-off" instead.  What then?  What point are you trying to make here?

TaskGroup.create_task returns a task object so that you can use the usual mechanisms, such as asyncio.wait() or an async queue to await and communicate with your tasks. You can and should do these things inside the task group, which will prevent it from prematurely waiting for all tasks to finish. The sole job of the task group is to ensure that all tasks are done by the time your code moves forward from the task group. It's not the job or the intention of TaskGroup to supplant asyncio.wait() or asyncio.Queue.

A callback based solution:
import asyncio

def task_done(task):
    try:
        value = task.result()
        msg = f"finished, return value: {value}"
    except asyncio.CancelledError as err:
        msg = "cancelled"
    except Exception as err:
        msg = f"failed: {repr(err)}"
    print(f"{task.get_name()} {msg}")

async def coro(i):
    await asyncio.sleep(i)
    if i == 4:
        1/0 
    return 100 + i 

async def main():
    try:
        async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg: 
            for i in range(1, 10):
                task = tg.create_task(coro(i), name=f"task #{i}")
                task.add_done_callback(task_done)
    except ExceptionGroup as group:
        print(f"{len(group.exceptions)} exception(s) in the task group")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

Total output:
task #1 finished, return value: 101
task #2 finished, return value: 102
task #3 finished, return value: 103
task #4 failed: ZeroDivisionError('division by zero')
task #8 cancelled
task #9 cancelled
task #7 cancelled
task #6 cancelled
task #5 cancelled
1 exception(s) in the task group


The arguments for using a TaskGroup, to which you refer, just describes the possibility of a task created with asyncio.create_task being garbage collected (and this destroyed) before it completes unless a reference is maintained to the task instance and code showing one way of doing this is provided. Aside from a task group automatically saving a reference to tasks created within the group, the tasks created have quite different behavior from those created with asyncio.create_task. For example, if one task raises an exception other than asyncio.CancelledError, all remaining tasks in the group are cancelled. If this is the behavior you need, then by all means the answer posted VPfB, which I have upvoted, is on point as is the comment made by Paul Cornelius.
But you may not want tasks to be automatically cancelled due to one failing task and thus a task group is not appropriate. There is more than one way to safely safe references besides the method shown in the docs. For example, if you want to use the asyncio.as_completed method you will by necessity already have references to the tasks:
import asyncio

async def job(task_id, sleep_time):
    print(f'Task {task_id} sleeping for {sleep_time} seconds.')
    await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)
    print(f'Task {task_id}: done')
    return task_id

async def main():
    tasks = [
        asyncio.create_task(job(i, 2 - i))
        for i in (1, 2)
    ]

    for task in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
        result = await task
        print(f'Task {result} has completed')

    del tasks  # Allow garbage collection of tasks

    ... # Other code

asyncio.run(main())

If you want/need to use a task group, then:
import asyncio

async def job(task_id, sleep_time):
    print(f'Task {task_id} sleeping for {sleep_time} seconds.')
    await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)
    print(f'Task {task_id}: done')
    return task_id

async def main():
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        tasks = [
            tg.create_task(job(i, 2 - i))
            for i in (1, 2)
        ]

        for task in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
            result = await task
            print(f'Task {result} has completed')

        del tasks  # Allow completed tasks to be garbage collected

asyncio.run(main())


I understand now.  It didn't occur to me at first that I could use a TaskGroup and then still also use the other methods (like as_completed) within the TG context by also doing some of my own task-management — mental block, I guess.
